# How to calculate automatically the number of pages

Tags: numbering, packages, page-numbering

When I create a page in latex, below everything appears the nº of page: 1 , 2 ...

Its possible to show  the page number above the total page?

For example:

```
 \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
 \begin{document}
  Hi % page 1
 \newpage
 Hi2 % page 2
 \end{document}
```

[image][image]

Thanks.

Comment: From a google search, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236389/page-x-of-y-in-latex-footer

Comment: Package `lastpage` can help

Comment: \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}
}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{plain}
Hi % page 1
\newpage
Hi2 % page 2
\end{document}